# Why does Dialogflow share the context of a conversation with all users?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es, chatbot

My problem is the following:

I have an agent in dialogflow, using only the platform;

no programming. The agent works great when interacting with one user, but when interacting with more than one user, the following happens:

> **user 1 says:** hello
>
> agent say: hello, what's your name?

---

> **user 2 says:** hello
>
> agent says: hello, what's your name?

assuming that two users are interacting simultaneously with the agent, that is, at the same moment ...

continuous...

> **user 1 says:** Darwin
>
> agent say: **Darwin** is a pleasure to greet you, do you have any
> questions?

---

> **user 2 says:** Jhon
>
> **agent says:** Jhon is a pleasure to greet you, do you have any
> questions?

so far everything is going great, the problem comes next ...

> **user 1 says:** yes, I have a question
>
> **agent say:** **`Jhon`** tell me what is your question

**He should have referred to Darwin not John**

Please how can I solve this, I use dialogflow ES

Comment: How are you setting up this test, are you using 2 tabs using the same google account in Dialogflow?

Comment: Hello Jordi, thank you very much for your answer.
No, the testing environment is as follows:
whatsapp -> AutoReply -> (Google Cloud platform Service Accounts) -> Dialogflow

Comment: I am using two users, different cell phones or WhatsApp accounts to interact with the agent. First I have created a service account in google cloud platform and I have downloaded a JSON file, which is required by a WhatsApp autoresponder.

Comment: I have this app installed on my cell phone. I have created a reply rule in the whatsapp autoresponder and that way it has worked like this so far. On the other hand, we might think that the problem may be the autoresponder,

Comment: but how else can I test the agent and make sure that there are no more layers that can intervene in the problem? so I can really know that the problem is in dialogflow and totally discard the other integrated technologies

Comment: I noticed that the Dialogflow simulator shares context when using the same google account, but I'm not sure if that plays a role when working with Whatsapp.